# Extraction from python over multiple lines

Tags: python, findall

I'm working with python and am trying to extract numbers from a .txt file and then group them into multiple categories. The .txt file looks like this:

```
IF 92007<=ZIPCODE<=92011 OR ZIPCODE=92014 OR ZIPCODE=92024

OR 92054<=ZIPCODE<=92058 OR ZIPCODE=92067 OR ZIPCODE=92075

OR ZIPCODE=92083 OR ZIPCODE=92084 OR ZIPCODE=92091 OR ZIPCODE=92672

OR ZIPCODE=92081 THEN REGION=1;      ** N COASTAL **;
```

This code was used to extract numbers from the first line:

```
import re

TXTPATH = 'C:/zipcode_mapping.txt'

f = open(TXTPATH,'r')

expr= "IF 92007<=ZIPCODE<=92011 OR ZIPCODE=92014 OR ZIPCODE=92024"

for line in f:
    L = line    
    print(L)
    matches = re.findall("([0-9]{5})",expr)
    for match in matches:
        print match
```

I can't seem to pull out the numbers from the other lines though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do:

```
matches = re.findall("([0-9]{5})",f.read())
```

You can extract them all at once - no need to loop over lines.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you just need to change 'expr' to 'L'?

```
matches = re.findall("([0-9]{5})",L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm being naive, but shouldn't you search for numbers in L, instead of in expr?

```
matches = re.findall("([0-9]{5})", L)
                                 ^^^^^^
```